# Evaluation of withdrawing an article undergoing Editorial Decision after two rounds of peer-review

Tags: paper-submission

I am reaching out to seek your advice regarding a situation I am facing with a scientific article that I have submitted for publication. After undergoing two rounds of peer review, my article has now been in the editorial decision phase for approximately two months. In the system, I have read favorable opinions from the three reviewers involved in the process. However, I have not yet received a final decision from the academic editor, despite my attempts to communicate with the editorial office.

Given this scenario, I am considering the possibility of withdrawing my article from the current journal and submitting it to another. This is the third scientific article that I have submitted, and its publication is crucial for my doctoral studies.

My specific questions for the forum are as follows:

1. Is it advisable to continue waiting for the editor's decision under these circumstances, or would it be more prudent to withdraw the article and submit it to another journal?
2. In case I opt for withdrawal, what are the ethical and professional implications that I should consider?
3. What are the experiences of other colleagues in similar situations and what course of action did they find most beneficial in the long term?

I appreciate in advance any guidance or shared experiences you can provide.

Comment: “Attempts to communicate with the editorial office” —- what is the specific nature of those attempts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have email for the specific editor, ask them for an update, mentioning that your degree is possibly at stake.

But withdrawal, which is your right until you sign over copyright, will only delay you. If you submit elsewhere the process starts over with no guarantee (or expectation) that it will be finished quickly.

I'd think your best bet is to try to keep communication open. Had the reviews been negative, withdrawal might be more reasonable.

Comment: Yes, if you are working with a specific editor, you might try emailing them through their work email rather than through the editorial system. It can be perceived as a bit pushy, but every conversation I have had with an editor indicates that your situation is one where they would be forgiving of a bit of pushiness.

Comment: They just rejected my paper. I have been contacting the editorial office to inquire about my case. At first, they told me that the decision was being delayed due to the Christmas holidays. Then, a couple of weeks ago, I wrote to them again and they told me to keep waiting. Finally, today they notified me that the paper is being rejected for editorial reasons. Well, time to submit to another journal.